# how To find out all vaues with preg_match_all

Tags: php

i have a complex string of data and i wan to make it simple my complext string look like this

```
{"status":true,"object":{"team1":{"teamId":"115927","name":"United CC","shortName":"UCC","logoImage":"https:\/\/cricket.entitysport.com\/assets\/uploads\/2020\/06\/ucc-120x120.png","players":[{"playersId":"99237","firstName":"Abhimanyu Singh","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Abhimanyu Singh","shortName":"Abhimanyu Singh","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"wk","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"26.50","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99239","firstName":"Shyamal Joshi","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Shyamal Joshi","shortName":"Shyamal Joshi","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"bat","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"9.00","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99244","firstName":"Pramod Bagauly","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Pramod Bagauly","shortName":"Pramod Bagauly","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"all","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"19.50","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99245","firstName":"Neelesh Pandit","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Neelesh Pandit","shortName":"Neelesh Pandit","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"all","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"10.00","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99247","firstName":"Kumal Deshmukh","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Kumal Deshmukh","shortName":"Kumal Deshmukh","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"all","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"2.00","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99249","firstName":"Arpan Shukia","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Arpan Shukia","shortName":"Arpan Shukia","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"bowl","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"11.00","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99251","firstName":"Amit Pangarkar","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Amit Pangarkar","shortName":"Amit Pangarkar","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"bowl","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"2.00","playing11":"1"}]},"team2":{"teamId":"115929","name":"Prague CC Kings","shortName":"PCC","logoImage":"https:\/\/cricket.entitysport.com\/assets\/uploads\/2020\/06\/pcck-120x120.png","players":[{"playersId":"99292","firstName":" Ramakrishnan ","middleName":"","lastName":"Sundareswaran","title":"Sharan Ramakrishnan Sundareswaran","shortName":"Sharan ","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"bat","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"0.00","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99293","firstName":"Arun Ashokan","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Arun Ashokan","shortName":"Arun Ashokan","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"bat","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"33.00","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99295","firstName":"Prakash Sadasivan","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Prakash Sadasivan","shortName":"Prakash Sadasivan","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"all","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"14.50","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99296","firstName":"Martin Glew","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Martin Glew","shortName":"Martin Glew","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"all","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"16.00","playing11":"1"}]},"userTeamId":"4444","matchId":"4343","earnPoints":"6.50","teamNumber":"1","captainId":"99239","viceCaptainId":"99247","isLineup":1},"message":"players","errCode":"11111"}
```

i am tring to making all team id and all players ids in a format like an simple string

```
 {"115927":[99222,99224,99226,99228,99230,99233],"115929":[99257,99264,99265,99266,99268]}
```

i try many types preg_match_all function but its not work is there any way to get this foramt with preg_match_all or any other function

Comment: Would you consider using [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) so you can manipulate an array, or must you do it through regex/preg_ functions?

Comment: sir can you simply iy please help me to do it

Comment: please do not asume the solution technique in the question (preg_match_all  might not be the solution)

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

Regex may not be the best way to do this as you're looking to nest the data and this can be really difficult to manage in regex unless you really know what you're doing..

Instead of this, using json_decode you can process the json as an array in PHP and restructure it into the format you want.

```
<?php
$json = '{"status":true,"object":{"team1":{"teamId":"115927","name":"United CC","shortName":"UCC","logoImage":"https:\/\/cricket.entitysport.com\/assets\/uploads\/2020\/06\/ucc-120x120.png","players":[{"playersId":"99237","firstName":"Abhimanyu Singh","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Abhimanyu Singh","shortName":"Abhimanyu Singh","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"wk","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"26.50","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99239","firstName":"Shyamal Joshi","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Shyamal Joshi","shortName":"Shyamal Joshi","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"bat","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"9.00","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99244","firstName":"Pramod Bagauly","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Pramod Bagauly","shortName":"Pramod Bagauly","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"all","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"19.50","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99245","firstName":"Neelesh Pandit","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Neelesh Pandit","shortName":"Neelesh Pandit","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"all","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"10.00","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99247","firstName":"Kumal Deshmukh","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Kumal Deshmukh","shortName":"Kumal Deshmukh","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"all","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"2.00","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99249","firstName":"Arpan Shukia","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Arpan Shukia","shortName":"Arpan Shukia","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"bowl","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"11.00","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99251","firstName":"Amit Pangarkar","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Amit Pangarkar","shortName":"Amit Pangarkar","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"bowl","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"2.00","playing11":"1"}]},"team2":{"teamId":"115929","name":"Prague CC Kings","shortName":"PCC","logoImage":"https:\/\/cricket.entitysport.com\/assets\/uploads\/2020\/06\/pcck-120x120.png","players":[{"playersId":"99292","firstName":" Ramakrishnan ","middleName":"","lastName":"Sundareswaran","title":"Sharan Ramakrishnan Sundareswaran","shortName":"Sharan ","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"bat","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"0.00","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99293","firstName":"Arun Ashokan","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Arun Ashokan","shortName":"Arun Ashokan","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"bat","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"33.00","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99295","firstName":"Prakash Sadasivan","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Prakash Sadasivan","shortName":"Prakash Sadasivan","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"all","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"14.50","playing11":"1"},{"playersId":"99296","firstName":"Martin Glew","middleName":"","lastName":"","title":"Martin Glew","shortName":"Martin Glew","country":"fi","photo":"","role":"all","ply_fantasy_points":"0","points":"16.00","playing11":"1"}]},"userTeamId":"4444","matchId":"4343","earnPoints":"6.50","teamNumber":"1","captainId":"99239","viceCaptainId":"99247","isLineup":1},"message":"players","errCode":"11111"}';

// turn this into an array
$array = json_decode($json, true);

$formatted = [];

foreach ($array['object'] as $team) {
    $teamId = $team['teamId'];

    foreach ($team['players'] as $player) {
        $formatted[$teamId][] = $player['playersId'];
    }
}

// $formatted now contains the format {teamId: [player1, player2], team2: [player3, player4]}
echo json_encode($formatted);
```

Using the code above you will have a `$formatted` array which now contains the data in the format you wish. Using `json_encode` you can then get it back to a json formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop and extract all players:

```
foreach(json_decode($json, true)['object'] as $team) {
    if(isset($team['teamId'])) {
        $result[$team['teamId']] = array_column($team['players'], 'playersId');
    }
}
```